# Different groups with single line, plotting in Excel

Tags: excel, plot

My problem:

I have a column of data and a column of condition (3 conditions).
My goal is to plot my data based on iteration (iteration would be my x axis), and colour different portions of the plot based on the condition.
Unfortunately, I have to use excel.

What I did:

I subdivided my column to 3 different columns based on condition

Then, I plotted them all together (scatter plot). So far everything is OK, but for the sake of presentation, I need to connect all of these points with a single line (the plotting option gives me three lines).

Any help would be appreciated ( I prefer a non VBA solution for the time being as I have to present them tomorrow and I didn't use Basic for years)?

Example:

Condition---OG-------G2-------G3-------G4

0-----------95.6-----95.6-----#N/A-----#N/A

1-----------95.6-----#N/A-----95.6-----#N/A

3.2---------95.6-----#N/A-----#N/A-----95.6

[image: Blue: G2; Red: G3; Yellow G4]

I want to connect a line between these 3 points (with different colour based on the condition column):
[image: What I need]

Comment: All your data is 95.6. From your example, above, I'm not sure if you want to plot 4 lines with 3 data points (OG, G2, G3, and G4), OR 3 lines with 4 data points (0, 1, 3.2).

Comment: What is the X and what is the Y for your scatter plot? This data set does not make sense. Can you manually draw a picture of how you want the chart to look? Use a file sharing service and show us more information.

Comment: I updated the question based on the comments (Thanks)

Comment: @rajah9 I want to plot OG column, connect all the points with a single line ( like the second grpah), but use different colour for different data points ( like figure 1). So I need one line with 3 data points.

Comment: @tylyn My x axis is iteration ( in this example: 1, 2, and 3), and my y axis is column "OG"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2013 (may be slightly different for other versions), merely select the data point to be joined up (here yellow, red would be necessary also) and select Solid line as shown:

[image: SO25371216 example]

Comment: I use 2010 version, when I select data points it can only connect data points of one of the columns together. It is possible that I am doing something wrong. I will try it on a 2013 version and let you know. However, I solved the problem based on your comment (plotted OG with G2, G3, and G4) and then connect the OG points together.